# CORS de Laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, cors

llevo mucho rato intentando hacer una consulta para rellenar un select de países.
Tengo Laravel 7.5, tengo agregado el paquete laravel CORS y estoy usando Fecth JS.
Tengo activado en la configuración de Cors.php, y cors ya está agregado en el middleware/Kernel.php
Pero no deja de generarme errores a pesar que he intentado muchas variantes.

perfil.blade.php

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
   const url = "http://country.io/names.json";

   async function getData(url = '') {
       const response = await fetch(url, {
           mode: 'no-cors', // no-cors, *cors, same-origin
           headers: {
               'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
               'Content-Type': 'application/json'
           },
       });
       const result = await response;
       return result;
   }

   getData(url)
       .then(data => {
           if (data.ok) {
               console.log('todo oc')
           } else {
               console.log('Respuesta de red OK pero respuesta HTTP no OK');
               console.log(data)
           }
       })
       .catch(function(error) {
           console.log('Hubo un problema con la petición Fetch:' + error.message);
           console.log(error);
       });

</script>
```

Y el error que me genera es:

```
Response { type: "opaque", url: "", redirected: false, status: 0, ok: false, statusText: "", headers: Headers, body: null, bodyUsed: false }
​
body: null
​
bodyUsed: false
​
headers: Headers {  }
​
ok: false
​
redirected: false
​
status: 0
​
statusText: ""
​
type: "opaque"
​
url: ""​
```

Comment: Estás haciendo la solicitud desde el mismo dominio?

Answer (score 0):

Buenas noches el error no esta en como tu haces la petición sino que el error esta en la api que te esta respondiendo, para que no te salgan problemas de cors la api que estas llamando tiene que responderle a tu fetch de la siguiente manera
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si la api es propia tuya solo ponla a responder de esta manera que te estoy diciendo, si la api es de un tercero puedes usar lamdas intermedios que consuman la api del tercero y te entregue la respuesta a ti como la necesites.